Why might the Consumer build function not called after notifylisteners?
consider
class AquariusProApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final LocalStorage cLocalStorage;
  final Database cDatabase;

  const AquariusProApp(
      {super.key, required this.cDatabase, required this.cLocalStorage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    myDebugPrint("in AquariusProApp build");
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Authenticator>(
            create: (context) => Authenticator(
                cDatabase: cDatabase, cLocalStorage: cLocalStorage)),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: kProgramName,
        theme: aquariumManagerTheme,
        home: Consumer<Authenticator>(builder: (context, authenticator, child) {
          myDebugPrint("in consumer");
          if (authenticator.isLoading) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (authenticator.hasToken) {
            return HomeView(cAuthenticator: authenticator);
          } else {
            return AuthenticatorView(cAuthenticator: authenticator);
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I change variables in the ChangeNotifier Authenticator class and call notifylisteners:
void resetAuthentication() {
    // we clear the saved token and reset the screen to the login page
    cLocalStorage.deleteSecureStorage(kAuthenticationInfo);
    _isPasswordBad = false;
    _isLoading = false; // we are NOT loading; we are headed to the authenticator screen
    _hasToken = false;
    myDebugPrint("in resetAuthentication");
    myDebugPrint("about to call notify 3");
    notifyListeners();
  }

However, the consumer build code is never called from this particular function. Why might this be?
There are numerous references to similar scenarios, but none solves my particular problem here.

The problem, not shown in the code above, was that I replaced the current route
Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HomeView(cAuthenticator: widget.cAuthenticator), // homeview will have a logout button, so it will need the authenticator
                    ),
                  );

So it ceased to exist.
Thanks to https://github.com/moffatman for the answer.
